# React Custom Hook and Firestore Snapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I created a React custom hook which listens to firestore database, i followed the documentation in firebase website but I'm having trouble when I re-render the component.
When I refresh my app the useEffect hook runs correctly but the listener inside `unsubscribe()` method doesn't. Here is the full code of the hook.

It works fine when the code recompiles itself after I save something in a component (first-render), but when it re-renders it shows as it if was always loading but it never executes the listener. Hope you can help me!

```
import { db } from "initFirebase";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface Payment {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  course: string;
  pagado: boolean;
}

export const usePaymentsCollection = () => {
  const [payments, setPayments] = useState<Payment[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<any>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = () => {
      try {
        db.collection("payments").onSnapshot(
          (snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.docs.length) {
              console.log("simona");
              let allDocs: Payment[] = [];
              snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                console.log(doc.data());
                return allDocs.push(doc.data() as Payment);
              });
              setPayments(allDocs);
              setIsLoading(false);
            } else {
              console.log("isEmpty");
              setIsLoading(false);
            }
          },
          (error) => {
            // ...
          }
        );
      } catch (e) {
        setError(e);
      }
    };
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [db]);

  return {
    payments,
    isLoading,
    error,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `unsubscribe` anonymous function you have provided is not a snapshot listener unsubscribe method. It is a function which creates a snapshot listener (and ignores the unsubscribe method returned from `db.collection("payments").onSnapshot()`).

You should set `unsubscribe` to the value returned from `db.collection("payments").onSnapshot()`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = db.collection("payments").onSnapshot(
    (snapshot) => {
      // ...
    },
    (error) => {
      // ...
    }
  );
  return unsubscribe;
}, [db]);
```

Additionally, by passing the array `[db]` into the `useEffect` hook, it will run again on rerender when the `db` state/prop is updated. Be sure that this is what you want - it probably isn't, since `db` is likely not a state/prop.